# how is it printing 2 as prime if 2%2 =0 (remainder is 0)

Tags: javascript

```
function showprimes(limit) {
    for(let number = 2; number <= limit; number++) {

        let isprime = true;
        for(let factor = 2; factor < number; factor++){
            if (number % factor === 0) {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime) console.log(number)
    }
}
```

in the following code initially number is equal to 2 in the outer loop and when it goes in the inner loop there factor is equal to 2  and then it checks if factor < number  which is not true as 2 is not less than 2  so when it checks if (number % factor === 0) i.e 2%2  which has to be 0 as remainder should be zero  so it shouldn't print 2 but it does. I cant understand why it does that

Comment: "and then it checks if factor < number which is not true" which is correct, so the code inside the inner for loop for that iteration doesn't execute (so your if-statement does not set isprime to false as it doesn't execute)

Comment: thanks for your answer helped me alot. I have one more question  does the inner loop start from 2 every time for a new outer loop??

Comment: Yes. The value for the first iteration of the inner loop will always be set to 2. On a side note, your prime check is really really bad. You can skip many checks if you change your code. For example, you check all even numbers and you check all factors above the square root of your number, which is unnecessary.

Comment: if its not too much to ask can u please show me how would you have written the code .I will be very thankful